# jQuery dataTables customized sorting is not working with Chinese numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatable, datatables

I have created [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zjgfq641/2/) for my question.

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "mysort-pre":  function (s)    { return s.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/g, ''); },
    "mysort-asc":  function (a, b) { return a.localeCompare(b); },
    "mysort-desc": function (a, b) { return b.localeCompare(a); }
});
$(function(){
    $('table').dataTable({
        order: [[ 0, "asc" ]],
        columnDefs: [ { type: "mysort", targets: 0 } ]
    });
});
```

To be short, in Chinese, `一`/`二`/`三` means `1`/`2`/`3` respectively.

By default, it sorts  `二` > `三` > `一` so I decided to write my own sorting.

There may (not) be some HTML tags in data fields, so I used regex to strip them in the `'-pre'` function.

As for `'-asc'` and `'-desc'` functions, I use `localCompare()` directly which should sort `三` > `二` > `一`.

But the result is not the same compared to what I had in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CAUSE**

Below is an excerpt from DataTables source code:

> Each ordering option can be described by three properties added to
>   this object:
>
> - `{type}-pre` - Pre-formatting function
> - `{type}-asc` - Ascending order function
> - `{type}-desc` - Descending order function
>
> All three can be used together, only `{type}-pre` or only 
>   `{type}-asc` and `{type}-desc` together. It is generally recommended 
>   that only `{type}-pre` is used, as this provides the optimal 
>   implementation in terms of speed, although the others are provided 
>   for compatibility with existing Javascript sort functions.

It means that `{type}-asc`/`{type}-desc` will not be called if `{type}-pre` is present.

Also, there is [Chinese (string)](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/chinese-string) sorting plug-in already available but it doesn't remove HTML tags as you want.

**SOLUTION**

So technically your sorting plug-in should be written as shown below to sort and remove HTML tags as well.

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "mysort-asc":  function (a, b) { 
        a = a.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '');
        b = b.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '');
        return a.localeCompare(b, "zh-CN-u-co-stroke"); 
    },
    "mysort-desc": function (a, b) { 
        a = a.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '');
        b = b.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '');       
        return b.localeCompare(a, "zh-CN-u-co-stroke"); 
    }
});
```

**DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zjgfq641/7/) for demonstration.

**NOTES**

Initially `localCompare` produced unexpected results

- `('三').localeCompare('二')` returns `-1` which means that `'三'` < `'二'`.

When I changed that to `('三').localeCompare('二', "zh-CN-u-co-stroke")`, it produced the correct results.

Comment: I use Chrome stable 41.  `localeCompare()` with `zh-TW` locale gives a wrong sorting [here](http://i.imgur.com/IQBLMZE.png). But it doesn't matters! My key question has been solved in the `CAUSE` section you mentioned. Thanks you!

Comment: @JackCherng, you're right. It works for me in Firefox, but doesn't work in Crome, strange. Is this a bug with `localCompare` or a different locale must be used, what do you think?

Comment: I just check `localCompare()` from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare). And `localeCompare(a, "co");` works both in Firefox and Chrome as expected!

Comment: @JackCherng, locale `"zh-CN-u-co-stroke"` works for me both in Firefox and Chrome, does it make sense to you? See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zjgfq641/7/).